# Linking two TextViews to scroll together if one is scrolled

Tags: java, android

I have two text views beside each other with multiple lines of text.

How can I make them both scroll together based on scrolling either one of them at the same time?

Comment: You can put both TextView in a layout.

Comment: @DheerajRijhwani read question carefully

Answer (score 0):

You can put both `TextView` as child to Scrolling View as parent

For example -

```
<NestedScrollView ....>
     <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ....>
          <LinearLayout android:weight="1" ....>
               <TextView android:text="Text1" ..../>
          </LinearLayout >
          <LinearLayout android:weight="1" ....>
               <TextView android:text="Text2" ..../>
          </LinearLayout >
     </LinearLayout >
 </NestedScrollView >
```

This is just an idea you can modify the way you want

Comment: This is a good idea. However, I have already put so many constraints in my layout and it will be difficult for me to reconfigure. It will be better if I can do it grammatically.